# boost bjam with emscripten

Tags: boost, clang, emscripten, bjam

I am having problems trying to compile my project with emscriten and boost's bjam build system. This is my user-config:

```
using clang
  : 5.4
  : emcc
  : <archiver>emar
    <ranlib>emranlib
  ;
```

This is how I build my project:

```
bjam toolset=clang-5.4 -j3 -d+2 --user-config=em.jam release
```

The problem I experience is, that bjam refuses to use the supplied archiver and ranlib. This causes a segmentation fault:

```
/bin/sh: line 1: 13572 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) "ar" rc "../.build/
```

I can't get it to use emar, no matter what I try. Running emar manually works without any problems.

Comment: This might not be the place. Either boost dev mailing list or emscripten #IRC would seem appropriate. Most likely the latter, as it's _their_ hoops to jump through. They don't have an _actual toolchain_ - it's wrappers all the way down, AFAICT

Comment: sehe, no, it is an ancient problem with bjam, I see posts all the way back to 2004 regarding this. emscripten is innocent, running emar manually works fine.

Comment: It's still _their_ hoops. Emscripten devs will be more motivated in getting the more daunting libs compiled, and perhaps they have established ways. Or they tell you upfront why not to even bother. Have you tried to contact them? _(Also, last time I checked emscripten had only very feeble emulation wrappers that barely worked with a limited set of automake projects. So either in the last two/three years they magically became a mature toolchain, or your "no" is way too resolute)_

Comment: sehe they are very good, even some of my odd SIMD code is now working.

Comment: code level compatibility is, of course, courtesy of LLVM. That's not the complicated part (from emscripten's POV). The code generating backend and toolchain compatibility are emscripten's complexity.

Comment: The clang Boost Build toolset just doesn't implement those options. If you need them please open a ticket at https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost or https://github.com/boostorg/build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now use the "emscripten" toolset included in Boost Build ([emscripten.jam](https://github.com/boostorg/build/blob/develop/src/tools/emscripten.jam)). It will handle everything except shared libs.

Comment: It produces `.bc` files for me. How to build static library `.a`?